# XmlPullParser can't find attribute with a colon in its name

Tags: java, xml, xmlpullparser

In my XML there's a tag with an attribute which has a name with a colon in it:

```
<GGS:bericht StUF:bestandsnaam="bestand.txt" >
```

I've tried all these combinations to try and return the value of this attribute:

```
parser.getAttributeValue(null, "StUF:bestandsnaam");
parser.getAttributeValue("StUF", "bestandsnaam");
parser.getAttributeValue(null, "bestandsnaam");
parser.getAttributeValue("bestandsnaam", "StUF");
```

... but they all return null.

If I manually remove the "StUF:" part of the attribute name, it works by calling:

```
parser.getAttributeValue(null, "bestandsnaam");
```

So how do you get the value of such an attribute? Without using the int-parameter version of getAttributeValue(), that is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "name with a colon in it" means the attribute is in a namespace.  Somewhere further up in the XML document you should find a namespace declaration on one of the ancestors of this element that looks like

```
xmlns:StUF="{something}"
```

and it's this `{something}` (which will probably look like either an HTTP URL or a `urn:...`) that you need to pass as the "namespace" parameter.  For example, if you had:

```
<root xmlns:GSS="urn:example:GSS" xmlns:StUF="http://stuff.com/namespace">
  <GGS:bericht StUF:bestandsnaam="bestand.txt" >
```

then the code would need to be

```
parser.getAttributeValue("http://stuff.com/namespace", "bestandsnaam");
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `getAttributeValue` [with the namespace parameter](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#getAttributeValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) says you need to enable namespace processing. Try enabling it at the beginning of the processing as in the [example](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#setFeature(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) for `setFeature`

```
setFeature(FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, true)
```